# Does sem_open allocate memory?

Tags: c, semaphore

If I use `sem_open()` in my program and then exit with `exit()` without `sem_close()` does it create memory leaks? Or is it just like with `open()/close()` functions that just closes the file descriptor?

Comment: Semaphores created with `sem_open` are OS resources that the OS will release when your process exits.

Comment: Okay thanks, so if I exit without sem_close() it doesn't create memory leaks

Comment: Most mainstream operating systems clean-up any memory leaks after the process exits anyways, memory leaks become a problem only when they start stacking up and the program is expected to run for a longer period of time.

Comment: It's a good habit to always clean up after yourself when you're done. Especially in long running programs, when you might not need a resource the full runtime of the program.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It'll only get cleaned up if you call `sem_unlink()` on it at some point.

Answer (score 1):

With decent OS, you should not worry for leaking of resources *at program exit*. The OS will reclaim the memory, open files, etc. Only *persistent* objects like files or share objects identifiers will survive the end of a program.

Memory (or other resources) leak are a problem because they are a hint of non cautious programming, and in real world are a problem for long running programs, or if they happen inside a loop. But it is generally seen as harmless to leak resources on an fatal error exit.

Comment: Named semaphores *are* persistent objects. They'll get closed at program exit, but not necessarily removed.

Answer (score 1):

As a side note,  under Linux/glibc, `sem_open()` actually creates a file in */dev/shm* directory (which is typically a **tmpfs** file system type mounted at system startup). The returned value of `sem_open()` is the address of the content of the file mapped into the process address space with a call to `mmap()`. So, some virtual memory is allocated in the process address space after a call to `sem_open()`. But as said in the previous answers and comments, the latter is deallocated at process exit time (except the semaphore file itself in */dev/shm*).